# How to speedup my update query associated with subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a query which is pretty that contains `LEFT JOIN` subquery. It takes 20 minutes to load completely.

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE orders AS o

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT obe_order_master_id, COUNT(id) AS count_files, id, added
    FROM customer_instalments 
    GROUP BY obe_order_master_id
) AS oci ON oci.obe_order_master_id = SUBSTRING(o.order_id, 4)

SET o.final_customer_file_id = oci.id,
    o.client_work_delivered  = oci.added

WHERE oci.count_files = 1
```

Is there any way that I can make this query runs faster?

Comment: create an index to the colnums that you use to join and filter,  if it does not exist yet

Comment: add `Explain Extended` before your query then execute, and add the results to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Where` condition in Temp Table and replace `WHERE` with `HAVING` Clause, this will eliminate unnecessary rows from temp table so reduce the filtering and may help to improve performance

```
UPDATE orders AS o
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT obe_order_master_id, id, added
   FROM customer_instalments 
   GROUP BY obe_order_master_id
   HAVING COUNT(id) = 1 
) AS oci ON oci.obe_order_master_id = SUBSTRING(o.order_id, 4)
SET o.final_customer_file_id = oci.id,
    o.client_work_delivered  = oci.added
```

Comment: Thank you mate it reduced to 27sec

Comment: Incidentally, an OUTER JOIN on an UPDATE query is a bit silly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create separate column for Order_id substring and make index on it. Then use this column in WHERE.